Transposing row-like data in DB table
I have a table where I store data of some parameters which are read step-wise. The number of parameters to be read can vary from use-case to use-case. The dataset of one step can be identified by its step number, the use-case by a uuid (dataset_uuid). The parameter_names "NAMExy" are not known at design time and need to be determined dynamically.



dataset_uuid
other_uuid
type
parameter_name
timestamp (varchar)
step
value




uuid1
uuid_a
TYPE1
NAME1
2024-09-05T15:04:22.000
0
1147.0


uuid1
uuid_b
TYPE2
NAME2
2024-09-05T15:04:22.000
0
17.569149


uuid1
uuid_c
TYPE2
NAME3
2024-09-05T15:04:22.000
0
14.86613


uuid1
uuid_a
TYPE1
NAME1
2024-09-05T15:04:24.000
1
1147.0


uuid1
uuid_b
TYPE2
NAME2
2024-09-05T15:04:24.000
1
17.569149


uuid1
uuid_c
TYPE2
NAME3
2024-09-05T15:04:24.000
1
14.896163


uuid1
uuid_a
TYPE1
NAME1
2024-09-05T15:04:25.000
2
1148.0


uuid1
uuid_b
TYPE2
NAME2
2024-09-05T15:04:25.000
2
17.569149


...








uuid2
uuid_k
TYPE1
NAME3
...
0
1147.0


uuid2
uuid_l
TYPE2
NAME4
...
0
1147.0


uuid2
uuid_m
TYPE2
NAME5
...
0
1147.0


uuid2
uuid_n
TYPE2
NAME6
...
0
1147.0


uuid2
uuid_o
TYPE2
NAME7
...
0
1147.0


uuid2
uuid_k
TYPE1
NAME3
...
1
1147.0


uuid2
uuid_l
TYPE2
NAME4
...
1
1147.0


uuid2
uuid_m
TYPE2
NAME5
...
1
1147.0


uuid2
uuid_n
TYPE2
NAME6
...
1
1147.0


uuid2
uuid_o
TYPE2
NAME7
...
1
1147.0



I would like to have an SQL-statement or function which transforms the data into something like this - rows contain parameter values and time stamps:



dataset_uuid
step
NAME1
NAME2
NAME3
NAME4
NAME5
NAME6
NAME7
timestamp




uuid1
0
1147.0
17.569149
14.86613
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
2024-09-05T15:04:22.000


uuid1
1
1147.0
17.569149
14.896163
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
2024-09-05T15:04:24.000


uuid1
2
1147.0
17.569149
...
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
2024-09-05T15:04:25.000


...











uuid2
0
NULL
NULL
NULL
val
val
val
val
timestamp


uuid2
1
NULL
NULL
NULL
val
val
val
val
timestamp


uuid2
2
NULL
NULL
NULL
val
val
val
val
timestamp


...












How can I achieve that in Postgresql ond Oracle?

SELECT 
    dataset_uuid,
    step,
    MAX(CASE WHEN parameter_name = 'NAME1' THEN value END) AS NAME1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN parameter_name = 'NAME2' THEN value END) AS NAME2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN parameter_name = 'NAME3' THEN value END) AS NAME3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN parameter_name = 'NAME4' THEN value END) AS NAME4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN parameter_name = 'NAME5' THEN value END) AS NAME5,
    MAX(CASE WHEN parameter_name = 'NAME6' THEN value END) AS NAME6,
    MAX(CASE WHEN parameter_name = 'NAME7' THEN value END) AS NAME7,
    MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp
FROM table1
GROUP BY dataset_uuid, step
ORDER BY dataset_uuid, step;

https://dbfiddle.uk/W0qHVgFZ

My problem is, that I do not know NAMEx at design time. Somehow I need to determine this at runtime.

See example with CROSSTAB for PostgreSql.
crosstab(source_sql, category_sql)
CROSSTAB source query will return rows with 3 column
row_name - row idetifier ,category - column name for transposed table, value - value in result table.
Create identifier rn for tuple(dataset_uuid,step,timestamp) as rank()over(dataset_uuid,step). Timestamp ignored:)
We use this identifier in CROSSTAB instead tuple.
with testN as(
  select *,rank()over(order by dataset_uuid,step) rn
  from test
)
select rn,parameter_name,value
from testN




rn
parameter_name
value




1
NAME1
1147


1
NAME2
17.569149


1
NAME3
14.86613


4
NAME1
1147


4
NAME2
17.569149


4
NAME3
14.896163


7
NAME1
1148


7
NAME2
17.569149


7
NAME4
18.1


10
NAME1
27.569149


10
NAME3
24.86613


12
NAME8
2147



Main query with crosstab.
category_sql as list of values
$$values('NAME1'),('NAME2'),('NAME3'),('NAME4'),('NAME5'),('NAME6'),('NAME7'),('NAME8')$$
SELECT a.dataset_uuid,a.step,a.timestamp,ct.* FROM 
crosstab(
$$with testN as(
  select *,rank()over(order by dataset_uuid,step) rn
  from test
)
select rn,parameter_name,value
from testN
  $$
,$$values('NAME1'),('NAME2'),('NAME3'),('NAME4')
         ,('NAME5'),('NAME6'),('NAME7'),('NAME8')$$
) AS ct(rn bigint, "NAME1" float, "NAME2" float, "NAME3" float, "NAME4" float
          , "NAME5" float, "NAME6" float, "NAME7" float
       , "NAME8" float)
left join (
  select distinct dataset_uuid,step,timestamp,rank()over(order by dataset_uuid,step) rn
  from test
)a on ct.rn=a.rn
ORDER BY rn;




dataset_uuid
step
timestamp
rn
NAME1
NAME2
NAME3
NAME4
NAME5
NAME6
NAME7
NAME8




uuid1
0
2024-09-05T15:04:22.000
1
1147
17.569149
14.86613
null
null
null
null
null


uuid1
1
2024-09-05T15:04:24.000
4
1147
17.569149
14.896163
null
null
null
null
null


uuid1
2
2024-09-05T15:04:25.000
7
1148
17.569149
null
18.1
null
null
null
null


uuid2
0
2024-09-05T15:04:22.000
10
27.569149
null
24.86613
null
null
null
null
null


uuid2
1
2024-09-05T15:04:24.000
12
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
2147



Test data



dataset_uuid
other_uuid
type
parameter_name
timestamp
step
value




uuid1
uuid_a
TYPE1
NAME1
2024-09-05T15:04:22.000
0
1147


uuid1
uuid_b
TYPE2
NAME2
2024-09-05T15:04:22.000
0
17.569149


uuid1
uuid_c
TYPE2
NAME3
2024-09-05T15:04:22.000
0
14.86613


uuid1
uuid_a
TYPE1
NAME1
2024-09-05T15:04:24.000
1
1147


uuid1
uuid_b
TYPE2
NAME2
2024-09-05T15:04:24.000
1
17.569149


uuid1
uuid_c
TYPE2
NAME3
2024-09-05T15:04:24.000
1
14.896163


uuid1
uuid_a
TYPE1
NAME1
2024-09-05T15:04:25.000
2
1148


uuid1
uuid_b
TYPE2
NAME2
2024-09-05T15:04:25.000
2
17.569149


uuid1
uuid_b
TYPE2
NAME4
2024-09-05T15:04:25.000
2
18.1


uuid2
uuid_b
TYPE2
NAME1
2024-09-05T15:04:22.000
0
27.569149


uuid2
uuid_c
TYPE2
NAME3
2024-09-05T15:04:22.000
0
24.86613


uuid2
uuid_a
TYPE1
NAME8
2024-09-05T15:04:24.000
1
2147



with testN as(
  select *,rank()over(order by dataset_uuid,step) rn
  from test
)
select dataset_uuid,step,rn,parameter_name,value
from testN




dataset_uuid
step
rn
parameter_name
value




uuid1
0
1
NAME1
1147


uuid1
0
1
NAME2
17.569149


uuid1
0
1
NAME3
14.86613


uuid1
1
4
NAME1
1147


uuid1
1
4
NAME2
17.569149


uuid1
1
4
NAME3
14.896163


uuid1
2
7
NAME1
1148


uuid1
2
7
NAME2
17.569149


uuid1
2
7
NAME4
18.1


uuid2
0
10
NAME1
27.569149


uuid2
0
10
NAME3
24.86613


uuid2
1
12
NAME8
2147



If necessary,  add extension tablefunc
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;

fiddle

My problem is, that I do not know NAMEx at design time. Somehow I need to determine this at runtime. As far as I understand your code, you need to knwo the parameter names upfront.
